# How to update staging SQL database to replicate the live database when on the same server

Tags: sql-server, database

I have two databases, staging and production, on the same Windows server. I am using a CMS and want the environments to be identical. I have taken backups of both databases using SSMS. What would be the best approach to update the staging database so that it is the same as the production database?

I have tried restoring the staging database with the production backup but it sets the staging database to single user. Usually when I have done this the databases have been on separate servers. Could someone advise on the best approach.

For example, do I take the staging database offline then complete the restore with the production backup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following steps and hope this helps others:

1. Took a backup of the production server
2. Went to IIS and stopped the staging site (otherwise you will not be able to take the staging database offline)
3. Took the staging database offline
4. Restored the staging backup with the live backup (I renamed the backup to the name of the staging database so not to cause confusion)

Answer (score 0):

What degree of latency is acceptable?  Do you need the staging DB to be identical to production in near-realtime, within the hour, or is a once-nightly update sufficient?  Depending on your needs, the best approach could be transactional replication, log shipping, backup/restore, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I only need to match the staging database with the production database periodically so that the staging and live site are the same.

Comment: Overnight backups and restore the staging database with a copy of live. It will in part go to help prove your backup process. You can schedule to happen has often or as little as you need.